# C# HttpClient tor socks4/5 proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, dotnet-httpclient, socks, flurl

I can set http proxy with this code:

```
public class CustomFlurlHttpClient : DefaultHttpClientFactory {
    public override HttpClient CreateClient(Url url, HttpMessageHandler m) {
        return base.CreateClient(url, CreateProxyHttpClientHandler("http://192.168.0.103:9090"));
    }

    private HttpClientHandler CreateProxyHttpClientHandler(string proxyUrl, string user = "", string passw = "") {
        NetworkCredential proxyCreds = null;
        var proxyUri = new Uri(proxyUrl);
        proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential (user, passw);
        var proxy = new WebProxy (proxyUri, false) {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = proxyCreds
        };
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = proxy,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };
        if (user != "" && passw != "") {
            clientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (user, passw);
        }
        return clientHandler;
    }
}
class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        run ();
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }

    async static void run() {
        using(FlurlClient client = new FlurlClient(c => { c.HttpClientFactory = new CustomFlurlHttpClient();})) {
            var result = await client.WithUrl("https://www.google.com").GetStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        };
    }
}
```

but not socks proxy. Any ideas how to do it? Or any other(not deprecated) rest client with async/await syntax supported?

Comment: Generally anything you can do with HttpClient, you can do with Flurl. Unfortunately I'm not finding any examples and I'm not very familiar with SOCKS personally. Maybe reframe this as an HttpClient question and someone will chime in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is to use `Extreme.Net` package, that provide socks proxy handler. For example, from code above we need to replace `CreateClient` method with this:

```
        public override HttpClient CreateClient(Url url, HttpMessageHandler m)
    {
        var socksProxy = new Socks5ProxyClient("127.0.0.1", 9150);
        var handler = new ProxyHandler(socksProxy);
        return base.CreateClient(url, handler);
    }
```

And it works!

Comment: Nice! That does look like it'll work, but it is possible to override the creation of just the MessageHandler and let the default factory create the HttpClient, as I'll demonstrate in a new answer.

Comment: Extreme.Net is deprecated?

Comment: according to nuget – yes

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 6 you can do it easily as [I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72343562/673187)

But here is a quick answer:

```
var proxy = new WebProxy
{
    Address = new Uri("socks5://localhost:8080")
};
//proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(); //Used to set Proxy logins. 
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = proxy
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

or to configure a named `HttpClient` to be created using `IHttpClientFactory`:

```
Services.AddHttpClient("WithProxy")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy
        {
            Address = new Uri("socks5://localhost:8080")
        };
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
                    Proxy = proxy
         };
    });
```

and when you injected `IHttpClientFactory` object:

```
httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("WithProxy");
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better option is to override `CreateMessageHandler` instead of `CreateClient` in your custom factory:

```
public class CustomFlurlHttpClient : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
        var socksProxy = new Socks5ProxyClient("127.0.0.1", 9150);
        return new ProxyHandler(socksProxy);
    }
}
```